# Is this a good implementation of interfaces?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, composition

I got this question about the best practice to using interfaces. Please, look at this code:

These are the interfaces:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public int getAcceleration();
}

public interface Flying extends Vehicle {
    public int getAltitude();
    public void up(int seconds);
    public void down(int seconds);
}

public interface Runner extends Vehicle {
    public int getSpeed();
    public void accelerate(int seconds);
    public void decelerate(int seconds);
}
```

This would be the implementation for the interface Runner:

```
public class RunnerImplementation implements Runner {
    Vehicle vehicle;
    int speed;

    public RunnerImplementation(Vehicle v) {
        vehicle = v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAcceleration() {
        return vehicle.getAcceleration();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void accelerate(int seconds) {
        speed += seconds * getAcceleration();
    }

    @Override
    public void decelerate(int seconds) {
        speed -= seconds * getAcceleration();
    }
}
```

This would be the implementation for the interface Flying:

```
public class FlyingImplementation implements Flying {
    Vehicle vehicle;
    int altitude;

    public FlyingImplementation(Vehicle v) {
        vehicle = v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAcceleration() {
        return vehicle.getAcceleration();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAltitude() {
        return altitude;
    }   

    @Override
    public void up(int seconds) {
        altitude += seconds * getAcceleration();
    }

    @Override
    public void down(int seconds) {
        altitude -= seconds * getAcceleration();
    }
}
```

And this would be the result, the FlyingCar class:

```
public class FlyingCar extends BaseVehicle implements Flying, Runner {
    Flying flying = null;
    Runner runner = null;

    public FlyingCar() {
        flying = new FlyingImplementation(this);
        runner = new RunnerImplementation(this);
    }   

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {
        return runner.getSpeed();
    }

    @Override
    public void accelerate(int seconds) {
        runner.accelerate(seconds);
    }

    @Override
    public void decelerate(int seconds) {
        runner.decelerate(seconds);
    }

    @Override
    public int getAltitude() {
        return flying.getAltitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void up(int seconds) {
        flying.up(seconds);
    }

    @Override
    public void down(int seconds) {
        flying.down(seconds);
    }
}
```

As you can see:

- I implemented each interface creating the classes `RunnerImplementation` and `FlyingImplementation`.
- Each implementation needs to know the current object to know its acceleration, I'm passing an `Vehicle` object as parameter to the constuctors.
- I defined `Runner` and `Flying` as extensions from `Vehicle`, because I want to show that they are related semantically, but this force me to implementing twice the method `getAcceleration()`. It's easy for one method, but if `Vehicle` had 100 methods, I have a problem... My first thought is that neither `Runner` nor `Flying` should to extend from `Vehicle`, but I will lose the semantic relation.

My questions:

- Is a good practice to implement the interfaces as I did it with `RunnerImplementation` and `FlyingImplementation` to be used in the class `FlyingCar`?
- Is there a better way to implement this?

TIA,

Comment: How can we know? It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Would recommend a move to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The only suggestion I have is with regards to naming conventions.  "Flying" is a bad choice for an interface name.  Typically, an interface name implies some kind of quality that certain object types might display, while other related object might not. "Flyable" is a more "correct" naming convention for an interface. Additionally, "flying" is a verb, and verb imply action. Methods denote the behavior (actions) of a class or interface. Therefore, "flying" is more appropriate for a method than for a class or interface.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Thank you for your advice. I'm new here. I will ask in that forum.

Comment: The question is too abstract to decide if this is a good design. Design is driven by requirements, its not a free-standing process. Without requirements you can't get a measure of how well the interfaces meet the requirments. You are practically tackling the problem from the wrong end.

Comment: @Durandal  Thank you for your comment. I will take care about how I will do my questions in the future.

Comment: @hfontanez  Thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just make `FLyingCar` implement `Flying` and `Runner` since it will also implement `Vehicle` (both interfaces extend it). I don't see the point of implementing interfaces just to use implementations as base classes for other classes (unless you will have large number of different object types).

Comment: But I see examples like this in another answer when we talk about multi inheritance. That's the reason why I did it like that...

Comment: If you know that you will have several Car objects then implementation of some methods can be identical, in this case it makes sense to have a concrete (or abstract) Car object that will serve as base class for more specific Cars. Your example doesn't require it at the moment.

Comment: One mistake I made was to write a too abstract example and not to talk about requirements as @Durandal said. That let my question as something not useful. Anyway, thinking about what I'm trying to do, yes, you have a point. Thank you.